# Windows 7 Forbid connecting to a specific wireless network

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking

Does anyone know how to tell windows 7 to bar a wireless network? It keeps logging into a random open one with no bandwidth my neighbors have instead of the good one we have here. I keep unchecking "automatically log in if available" and it keeps re-checking itself. I want it to NEVER log into this network no matter what without manual intervention. I do not want to disable auto connecting, just tell it "do not ever connect to this one without my express permission".